# Removendo valores duplicados de um array

Tags: php

Estou conseguindo fazer a listagem de maneira correta, mas alguns valores estão duplicados e queria remove-los e não consigo de jeito nenhum... se alguém puder me ajuda, fico bastante agradecido.

// Criando variavel

```
$sector_list = $s->getSector();
```

// Listando

```
<?php foreach($sector_list as $value): ?>
    <option>
        <?php echo $value['sector']; ?>
    </option>   
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

O Retorno acontece corretamente, mas com valores duplicados.

Comment: `array_unique()`  https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_unique.asp

Answer (score 1):

Segundo a [documentação do php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php), podes usar a função `array_unique`.

O primeiro parâmetro é o array, e o segundo é a SORT_FLAG (não é obrigatório) .. Abaixo segue exemplo:

```
<?php
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);

// Irá printar:
/// Array
// (
//     [a] => green
//     [0] => red
//     [1] => blue
// )

?>
```